# What is the Oracle date formatting mask for time zones?

Tags: oracle, date, formatting, mask

I need to insert a date format from an outside source which includes the three letter code for time zone, but the **TZD** formatting mask does not seem to work...

```
insert into blah
    values (to_date('Thu, 18 Feb 2010 08:37:00 EST','Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZD'));

ORA-01821: date format not recognized
```

If I remove the "TZD"...

```
insert into blah
    values (to_date('Thu, 18 Feb 2010 08:37:00','Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

1 row created.
```

What is the proper mask for such an insert statement in Oracle?

```
desc blah
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 D                          DATE
```

Edit: I changed the table column from DATE type to TIMESTAMP type and got the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Date columns don't have timezone as an option.  You'd have to create the column as data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`or`TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`, and besides, the `TO_DATE` function doesn't understand the TIME ZONE format mask you're applying.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE T
  2  (DT DATE,
  3   TS TIMESTAMP,
  4   TSTZ TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  5   TSLTZ TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO T (TSLTZ) VALUES 
  2  (to_timestamp_tz('Thu, 18 Feb 2010 08:37:00 EST','DY, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZD'))
  3  /

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO T (TSTZ) VALUES 
  2  (to_timestamp_tz('Thu, 18 Feb 2010 08:37:00 EST','DY, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZD'))
  3  /

1 row created.
```

Answer (score 0):

If timezone is not relevant for you, just strip it from the string using SUBSTR function and insert as in your second example.