# Cast a string into datetime in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, casting

How can I cast this string date to datetime in oracle.

```
Sun Apr 21 21:32:13 IRDT 2013
```

"IRDT" is the time zone and its equal in all records.

Comment: What is `IRDT`? Is that a time zone?

Comment: so you want from that string to get a date or a timestamp?

Comment: There are tons of examples available on Stackoverflow. Have you tried any of them? For example, ["What is the Oracle date formatting mask for time zones?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291082/what-is-the-oracle-date-formatting-mask-for-time-zones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about timezone and it is equal in all records you can try

```
SELECT TO_DATE('Sun Apr 21 21:32:13 IRDT 2013'
              ,'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS "IRDT" YYYY') "date"
FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
|                         DATE |
--------------------------------
| April, 21 2013 21:32:13+0000 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11169)**

But if you need to take into account and store timezone info then you might want to use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type and `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this : http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Basically you would use to_Date('Sun Apr 21 21:32:13 IRDT 2013','mask'), and you create the mask string using the table from that link