# Find non-numeric character instead of a numeric character

Tags: oracle

I work with oracle 11 G

and I want to update my table

but I have a problem in format of date

the type of my column is **timeStamp**  and this is an example of date in my column :
 **11/12/05 16:08:00,000000000**

this is my java code

```
String query = "UPDATE transfers SET date_closed_transfer = '" +
                new Date() + "', date_arch = '" +
                new Date() + "', date_archhj = '" +
                dateArchHj + "',action_type = '2',status_transfer = '" + status +
                "' WHERE id_transfer = '" + id + "'";
```

this is my query :

```
 UPDATE transfers

    SET date_closed_transfer = to_date('Mon Mar 24 10:39:25 GMT 2014','dd/mm/yy')',

    date_arch = to_date("Mon Mar 24 10:39:25 GMT 2014","dd/mm/yy")', 

    date_archhj = '1435/5/23',
    action_type = '2',
    status_transfer = 'AP'
    WHERE id_transfer = 'TR-70'
```

but I have this error :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01858: Caractère non numérique trouvé à la place d'un caractère numérique
```

**Updated :**

I try  with this query :

```
UPDATE transfers SET date_arch = to_timestamp_tz('Tue Mar 25 09:29:14 GMT 2014','DY Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY'), date_archhj = '1435/5/24',action_type = '2',status_transfer = 'A' WHERE id_transfer = 'TR-78'
```

but I have this error :

**Erreur SQL : ORA-01846: ce n'est pas un jour de semaine valide
01846. 00000 -  "not a valid day of the week"**

also I try with :

```
UPDATE transfers SET date_closed_transfer = '25/03/2014', date_arch = '2014-03-25 09:59:47.123', date_archhj = '1435/5/24',action_type = '2',status_transfer = 'A' WHERE id_transfer = 'TR-61'
```

but also I have an error :

**Erreur SQL : ORA-01843: ce n'est pas un mois valide
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"**

this is a valid example of date which should e in my column

**31/03/02 00:00:00,000000000**

Comment: Can you use bind variables instead of concatenating literals?

Answer (score 1):

The format mask that you provide in the TO_DATE function needs to match the string. Plus, you can use the TO_TIMESTAMP function, because your column is of TIMESTAMP datatype. Therefore, it should be as below:

**Updated query:**

```
to_timestamp_tz('Mon Mar 24 10:39:25 GMT 2014','DY Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY')
```

References:

[Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291082/what-is-the-oracle-date-formatting-mask-for-time-zones)

[The Oracle TO_DATE Function](http://psoug.org/definition/TO_DATE.htm)

Comment: thank you for your answer  but I still have an error :

Comment: I checked the query again. TZR (Time Zone Region) works for your timestamp string. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm