# Oracle giving ORA-01821 on a format that appears to be valid

Tags: oracle, to-date

Calling

```
SELECT TO_DATE('Mon Sep 22 18:02:41 CDT 2014', 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY') FROM Dual;
```

I get

```
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"
```

I put together the format string from [these Oracle instructions](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php).  I tried both "TZR" and "TZD", neither works.

```
DY  Abbreviated name of day.
MON Abbreviated name of month.
DD  Day of month (1-31).
HH24    Hour of day (0-23).
MI  Minute (0-59).
SS  Second (0-59).
TZD Daylight savings information. For example, 'PST'
TZR Time zone region.
YYYY    4-digit year
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291082/what-is-the-oracle-date-formatting-mask-for-time-zones  Maybe use to_timeStamp_TZ?
 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions194.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TO_DATE doesn't support timezone.

I think you need to use [to_timestamp_TZ()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions194.htm) to do what you're after...

```
SELECT To_TimeStamp_TZ('Mon Sep 22 18:02:41 2014 CDT', 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY TZD') 
FROM Dual;
```

Gives you something like (with my NLS paramaters)

```
22-SEP-14 06.02.41.000000000 PM AMERICA/CHICAGO
```

Also note the data type must be TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE Data Type; or oracle just drops the timezone information w/o error.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG238

Comment: Now if only 1: Oracle were to document that TZD doesn't work with TO_DATE, and 2: To_TimeStamp_TZ could handle "EDT"

Comment: It's there by omission does that count?  :P (the fact that they don't talk about it means it's not supported right?)

Comment: @GregDougherty - what do you mean by "only if Oracle were to document that TZD doesn't work with TO_DATE"? From the Oracle documentation: **The following datetime format elements can be used in timestamp and interval format models, but not in the original DATE format model: FF, TZD, TZH, TZM, and TZR.** https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212   And no, I don't work for Oracle :-)

Comment: @mathguy Go to the directions for To_Date https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php Now try to find any warning that TZ* don't actually work with To_Date.  I don't see anything on that page saying that.  Do you?

Comment: @GregDougherty - Why would I go to "techonthenet" (who are they???) and not to the official Oracle web site? Someone who has nothing to do with Oracle may write whatever they want on the web, that is not considered "official Oracle documentation."

Comment: @mathguy Well, you're right, it's not Oracle.  It is, however, the top hit on google when looking for Oracle To_date