# convert oracle date format to insert

Tags: sql, oracle

I am recovering the insert from a log file after the application was unable to insert it.

For security reasons, unfortunately I can't put the insert here.

I need to insert some data but I'm having problems with my insert with the date.
How should i convert this date 'Tue Dec 31 12:28:59 BRT 2019' to be able to insert in a date column.

[]´s

Comment: Is it a date, or is it a string? And where is it coming from? How have you tried to insert it, and what happened? If it's a string do you need to adjust for the time zone (e.g. to UTC), or can you ignore that?; and will it always be BRT?

Comment: Thank you for proposing to help! Yes it is a string, these are some inserts that gave a problem and I recovered them from a log. I can ignore UTC all are BRT. This is the error > ora-01858 a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.

Comment: Does this help: [What is the Oracle date formatting mask for time zones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291082/what-is-the-oracle-date-formatting-mask-for-time-zones)

Answer (score 7):

A variation on @OldProgrammer's replace approach is to embed the 'BRT' as a character literal in the format mask:

```
select to_date('Tue Dec 31 12:28:59 BRT 2019',
  'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS "BRT" YYYY',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') as result
from dual;

RESULT
-------------------
2019-12-31 12:28:59
```

I've included the optional third argument to `to_date()` so that day and month names are always interpreted in English; otherwise the session settings would be used, which could cause it to fail.

---

I know you aren't interested in the time zone, but if you did want to take that into account, you're still a bit stuck as the abbreviation BRT can't be translated to a single region or offset.

With a limited range of abbreviations that are unambiguous to you, you could go back to `replace()` to substitute the region name instead, e.g.:

```
select to_timestamp_tz(replace('Tue Dec 31 12:28:59 BRT 2019', 'BRT', 'America/Sao_Paulo'),
    'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY',
    'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') as ts_result,
  cast(to_timestamp_tz(replace('Tue Dec 31 12:28:59 BRT 2019', 'BRT', 'America/Sao_Paulo'),
    'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY',
    'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') as date) as date_result,
  to_timestamp_tz(replace('Tue Dec 31 12:28:59 BRT 2019', 'BRT', 'America/Sao_Paulo'),
    'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY',
    'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') at time zone 'UTC' as utc_ts_result,
  cast(to_timestamp_tz(replace('Tue Dec 31 12:28:59 BRT 2019', 'BRT', 'America/Sao_Paulo'),
    'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY',
    'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') at time zone 'UTC' as date) as utc_date_result
from dual;

TS_RESULT                               DATE_RESULT         UTC_TS_RESULT             UTC_DATE_RESULT
--------------------------------------- ------------------- ------------------------- -------------------
2019-12-31 12:28:59.0 AMERICA/SAO_PAULO 2019-12-31 12:28:59 2019-12-31 14:28:59.0 UTC 2019-12-31 14:28:59
```

This is slightly simplified by not having to worry about DST here. But as you can see you can then convert easily to another time zone if needed.

Comment: Understood, you can replicate your examples and they are already noted if I need to put the location.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work:

```
select to_date(replace('Tue Dec 31 12:28:59 BRT 2019','BRT',''),'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS  YYYY') from dual
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tested it and as informed by @Alex Pool , I had to add 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH' because the DB defaults is NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE. Anyway after the inclusion of this parameter it worked. Very thks!

Comment: yeah, I did not think of the language.  thanks @alex Pool